# Error in writing data in eeprom in Nodemcu

Tags: arduino, esp8266, nodemcu, eeprom, arduino-esp8266

i am writing the data in eeprom of nodemcu esp8266 12e but their is error in writing data. after restarting the board the value is lost again not store for long . help to solve this issue. 
when i am writing the data in eeprom on board the data is write in eeprom but after restarting the board the value will lost.

```
  memcpy (msg,message.payload,message.payloadlen);
  Serial.print(msg);
  int compare = 1;
  if (0==(compare=(strncmp("ON",msg,4)))) {
    val = 1 ;
    digitalWrite(LED,HIGH);
    EEPROM.write(addr,val);
    compare = 1;
  }
  else if (0==(compare=(strncmp("OFF",msg,4)))) {
    val = 0 ;
    digitalWrite(LED,LOW);
    EEPROM.write(addr,val);
    compare = 1;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

So, the ESP8266 does not actually have an EEPROM. The authors of the Arduino SDK instead map out a small section of flash (You can find the actual size in the linker scripts) to be used for the virtual EEPROM.

When you call `EEPROM.write(addr, x)`, it stores the data in a shadow copy of the virtual-EEPROM, but, does not store it in flash until `EEPROM.commit();` is called.